# creating flask table from data

Tags: python, flask

I'm being trying to put data into a table in flask but its creating a new row for each character for some reason instead of just putting the full string into the row.

code:

```
@app.route('/') 
def logs():
    output = ''
    try:
        conn = redis.StrictRedis(host='redis', port=6379)
        for key in conn.scan_iter("log.g*"):
            value = str(conn.get(key))
            output += "str(key)+ '--' + value"

            return render_template('view.html', data=output)
```

table code:

```
<table>
    {% for row in data %}
    <tr>
        {% for value in row %}
        <td>{{ value }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the thing is that your output / data is absolutely unstructured - it is just one big string. You want to make for example a list:

```
    output = []
    conn = redis.StrictRedis(host='redis', port=6379)
    for key in conn.scan_iter("log.g*"):
        value = str(conn.get(key))
        output.append("str(key)+ '--' + value")

    return render_template('view.html', data=output)
```

(In your code your return statement is inside the cycle, which means that the cycle will run just once.

The code above will create a list and then the template:

```
<table>
   {% for value in data %}
   <tr>
        <td>{{ value }}</td>
   </tr>
   {% endfor %}
</table>
```

will print each list member into a table cell. Aside of that, we cannot tell what you want to have in one table row.